# Outlook 2016 - old vba code to fire rules won't run

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

Why is this code to run all enabled rules does not run in outlook-2016?
I used it without any problem on outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013, but it is not working in outlook 2016.

```
Sub OrginalRunActiveCatInboxRules()

Dim Session As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim Report As String
Dim currentItem As Object
Dim currentRule As Outlook.Rule
Dim rules As Outlook.rules
Dim ruleList As String
Set Session = Application.Session

Set rules = Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()

For Each currentRule In rules

   If currentRule.RuleType = olRuleReceive Then         
'determine if it’s an Inbox rule, if so, run it
       If currentRule.Enabled Then
           If Left(currentRule.name, 4) = "Cat." Then
               MsgBox currentRule.name
               currentRule.Execute ShowProgress:=True   
' Sortering niet laten zien
'               ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & currentRule.Name
           End If
       End If
   End If
 Next


' tell the user what you did
' ruleList = "These rules were executed against the Inbox: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
' MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunAllActiveInboxRules"
Set rules = Nothing
Set currentRule = Nothing
End Sub
```

The codes runs until next, but gives a error there. It does not matter if the first rule is enabled or not, starts with Cat. or not. It just won't go to the next item in the loop, but generates a error.

What can I do to make the code working again?

Comment: What *is* the error?

Comment: Error: -2146664191 (800c8101) According to the help this error has something to to wit the OlkCategory.BackColor Property, Which seems nonsense to me.

Comment: The rule itself doesn't seem to be relevant. If I leave out the execution the error pops up. I set Outlook to perform macro's without any restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the rules wizard if some of the rules are marked 'From other computer'.
If you have any like this, then the code will break at the line:

```
For Each currentRule In rules
```

I have the same issue now - took me a lot of troubleshooting to figure this out. One more thing that could be an issue: if any of the rules are broken, for example refer to a directory that does not exist, the rules object will not contain any rules.

If troubleshooting the above, remove all the suspicious rules and start adding them one by one back.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this same issue when writing a macro in Outlook 365 to run some rules. I don't know why, but as J. Farro mentioned in their answer, certain conditions being enabled on any rule seems to cause the run-time error '-2146664191 (800c8101)' when trying to enumerate the Rules object.

In my case the "through the specified account" condition on one of my rules was the culprit. Removing that condition stopped the error. If you aren't able to remove the condition, you can use a different approach to index the Rules object as mentioned in [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/rules/managing-rules-in-the-outlook-object-model):

> You can retrieve each rule in a Rules collection by indexing the collection using Rules.Item(Index), with Index being either the name of the rule (the default property Rule.Name), or a value ranging from 1 through the total number of rules in the collection, Rules.Count.

You can use this approach with error handling disabled to skip the rule(s) with troublesome conditions that can't be accessed through VBA

```
Sub PrintAllRules()
Dim Rules As Outlook.Rules
Dim Rule As Outlook.Rule

Set Rules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules

For i = 1 To Rules.Count
    'if the Rules.Item method below fails, Rule will retain it's value
    'from the previous loop iteration so we need to clear it each time
    Set Rule = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rule = Rules.Item(i)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Rule Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Rule " & i & " could not be accessed"
    Else
        Debug.Print Rule.Name
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, you will still not be able to access the rule(s) with the troublesome condition, but those rules won't break your code and prevent you from accessing all your other rules.

Answer (score -1):

One of mine was marked "on this computer" when I unselected this option, the script worked again.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30448130)

Comment: A rule marked "on this computer" was causing the same error that OP received. As the poster above me commented, having a rule marked "From other computer" causes a break in the code. Similarly, a rule marked "On this computer" caused a break.